# time-out between laravel app and meilisearch server

Tags: php, laravel, digital-ocean, laravel-forge, meilisearch

I have two apps both hosted on DO through Laravel Forge and both in the same region. One hosts my application, the other is a dedicated Meilisearch server. Both are in each other's server network. I've got the correct Meilisearh credentials in my app's .env and my Scout config is correct.

I'm getting a 504 gateway time-out when visiting the home page of the app (which has a search feature) and when trying to run `php artisan scout:import "App\Models\ModelName"` when ssh'ed into my application server I get the following error:

```
MeiliSearch\Exceptions\CommunicationException
cURL error 28: Failed to connect to "SERVER IP ADDRESS" port 7700: Connection timed out
```

I'm not sure how else to troubleshoot this so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

MeiliSearch is probably on port 80